# For loop with array unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays which im checking against in a for loop, but am stuck on how to make the for loop work on the array.

The array is build like this in json_encode:

```
var bdata = {"1":["50","50","0","Player1"],"2":["1500","1000","1000","Player2"]};
```

The array i am comparing it against is encoded like this:

```
var vdata = {"uid":"1","total":"1","w":"1","t":"1","s":"1","g":"1","l":"0","upd":"0"};
```

Then i tried to create the loop by converting them into arrays but it does not work:

```
bdata = JSON.parse(bdata);
vdata = JSON.parse(vdata);
    for(bdata[0] as bid){
    if(vdata["w"] >= bdata[bid][1] && vdata["g"] >= bdata[bid][0] && vdata["s"] >= bdata[bid][2]){
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<br/>"+bdata[bid][3];     
        }else{
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<br/><font color='red'>"+bdata[bid][3]+"</font>";     
        }
    }
```

But the error i get is : Unexpected identifier

I'm not even sure im looping the first array correctly ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: You don't have arrays, you have objects. You don't need JSON.parse() because they're already objects, not strings. And your for loop syntax is wrong. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects and the [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop. (Sorry, I don't have time to write a proper answer.)

Comment: @jfriend00 compare data from the two returned arrays in the if statement and output depending on if the comparisons were true or false. Based on the if statement's checks.

Comment: But, the data in the two data structures is completely different form.  I have no idea what items in one structure you want to compare to the other.  You have to be more specific about what you're trying to compare to what.  What does the first "50" in `bdata` get compared to in `vdata`?   What does `player1` get compared to?

Comment: in the first array for example: im checking first value of the number (such as "1":) (which is 50) against the value of "w" in the second array. Imagine something costs 50 water. But the user only has 1 water "w":"1"  means in the if statement the user does not have enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plenty of syntax errors. For example

1. For loop syntax. Either use

   ```
   for (init counter; condition; post loop operation)
   eg,
   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
   ```

   or

   ```
   for (property in collection)
   ```
2. Greater-than-or-equal-to comparison operator

   ```
   >=
   ```

   not

   ```
   =>
   ```
3. You don't need to use `JSON.parse()`, you already have JSON objects

Comment: I can't use a counter because that assumes each position starts at a given number and goes in patterned increments.. which it does not.

Comment: @Dave Did you even read my answer? See the second variant on the for loop; `for(property in collection)`

Comment: I saw it but not sure how i would use it in terms of correct wording do you have a jsfiddle example?